# How does the mobile 3.5mm audio port work, and Can I light a LED from it?

Tags: led, audio, mobile, headphones

I am trying to do this, light a LED from the headphone wire(mobile) but it seems it gives ac in there, I don't have much idea, please help.

Comment: I have actually wondered the same myself. Both answers below state "No", but none provides any quantitive data. I would suspect IF this is possible, you will need some special "song" to play during the experiment. For example, you can get Audacity and create an all-max-values song, then upload it and play it, to get your DC offset.

Comment: The answer is "no". There is insufficient voltage to drive a LED. You will need a power source

Comment: Yes it can. There are ir led that can be used to control a camera from a standard headphone jack.  And see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26785/power-led-from-headphone-jack

Answer (score 2):

If you must light your led without an external supply you could consider a small audio stepup transformer.Perhaps something out of a dead transistor radio.Otherwise you could build a diode pump that say quadrupled the voltage.Use shottkey diodes for your diode pump because they waste less voltage .Use a red led for your experiment  because they need less volts than the other colors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, audio signals are AC. Headphone voltages will be too low to light an LED.

Comment: So, is there any way that i can work around that?

Comment: @HrishikeshBarman Without some sort of additional power supply - no.

Comment: @HrishikeshBarman yes and no. Its possible, if the Vf of the LED is low enough, you can drive a square wave tone (using an app like function generator by keuwlsoft), 180deg out of phase, place the LED across the L & R channels, so that as one channel swings + and the other - itll induce the greatest possible potential difference between them hopefully lighting the LED at 1/2 thr frequency. But do not expect miracles. This technique is used with an app like IRplus(wave) by binarymode to drive IR LEDs now that phones dont have IR blasters. NOT AFFILIATED WITH APPS, just what I use personally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know for sure, but I would be checking out the mic wire. It could have bias current designed to power electret mics. Easy enough to check - just measure the mic to GND voltage, and then to be sure put in 1k - 10k resistor there, and measure voltage again. From these two measurements you should be able to determine open circuit voltage of that source, and internal resistance.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you by headphone wire you mean the 3.5mm jack of your phone.

First consider lighting a LED. To light a LED you need a DC voltage and a few mA of current. Your audio jack isn't built to source current or provide DC voltage. It just transmits AC signal to your headphones.There is no way in which you will be able to light a LED from your jack.

You cannot use it for a purpose which it is not intended to serve.

Comment: Phone audio jacks are designed to source some current, they do after all power your headphones!
In fact, I suspect that the jack may even be able to source enough current to drive a small, low power LED. 

In this case, I think it will be the small signal voltage which will be the limiting factor and not the current sourcing capability.

Comment: Yes, you can light an LED with your HeadPhone Jack (HPJ), this is how the HPJ IR LED blasters work. Yes, the amp circuits aren't that strong, but we are talking a flash of light, not constantly sourcing DC. Meaningful DC current cannot and should not be sourced from the HPJ. However by placing an LED across the L&R channels and playing a wave (preferably square) 180deg out of phase enough differential can be generated to light a low voltage LED (IR, red, green, some yellows). IR LEDs back to back so one lights on either side of the cycle is common for replacing the loss of installed blasters.

Comment: Addendum: Another potential configuration, is 2 LEDs with - legs to GND, + legs to L and R channels separately. However, to ensure the highest possible potential differential tying the LEDs legs together back to back, + of one and - of the other, both sides, across L and R usually taps the most the audio amps can push. A fast frequency could make them appear constant, but not necessarily bright. Using a battery and a NPN transistor with base on a L or R channel, and the battery - bonded to phone GND will allow the battery to drive any load the NPN can pass.